# How to prevent backbone.js from sharing events across view childs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a master view to create lists. this view has a click event to "load more items".
I have two sub views extending the master view.
my problem is, when I click on one views "load more" button, it affects the other view (if loaded before). I understand I have to close views before initializing another one, but since my views are extending the master view, this method won't work (it closes the master object, and the other child views won't initialize):

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function(){
  this.remove();
  this.unbind();
}
```

my master view:

```
App.Views.List = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .load-btn' : 'loadMore'
    },
    loadMore: function(e)
    {
        this.collection.increase().fetch({
            add: true
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }  
}
```

note that .increase is a custom method to increase the api parameter.

a child view:

```
App.Views.Projects = App.Views.List.extend({
    initialize: function()
    {
        this.itemView = App.Views.Project;
        this.collection = new App.Collections.Projects();
        this.parent('initialize');
    },
    render: function()
    {
        this.template = _.template(App.Tpl.get('projects.list'));
        this.parent('render');
    }
});
```

note that .parent is a custom method to call the master view's methods.
so when I click on load-more button in a view, it tries to call loadMore methods on all views extending from the master view if already initialized.

What should I do?

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457915/how-can-i-stop-event-propagation-with-backbone-js)?

Comment: There is too much _noise_ in here: are you sure your _custom methods_ `.increase` and `.parent` are not the responsable of this behavior?. Beware that if all these Views are sharing the same `el` DOM Element are gonna share the events on it.

Answer (score 1):

`App.Views.Projects` extends `App.Views.List` and doesn't define events, so it is inherited form the parent view. This would mean that all `.load-btn` elements inside a project view have the handler set.

Maybe you could fix this by adding an empty events hash to the project view, ie.

```
App.Views.Projects = App.Views.List.extend({
  events: {},
  initialize: function()
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use e.stopPropagation() instead of prevent default. That helped me on a similar problem.